# How to print all the list values in the mail body without square bracket in java

Tags: java

Here is my code : Inside the sendmail() method, am not able to get all the file names without square bracket. Please help me to solve this. Here, finalvalue is an arraylist. If i use, .get() am getting OutofBoundException.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy z");
String LastModifiedDate=sdf1.format(file1.lastModified());
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy z");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
  if(sdf1.format(file1.lastModified()).compareTo(formatter.format(date))==0){
    strFilenameModifieddate=FilesInsideFolder+":"+LastModifiedDate;
    System.out.println(strFilenameModifieddate);
    list.add(strFilenameModifieddate);
    System.out.println("Final:"+list);
    totalElements = list.size();
    System.out.println("total elements:"+totalElements);
    for(index=0; index <totalElements; index++)
    {
    //System.out.println(index);
    System.out.println("Currently modified Files1:"+list.get(index));
    finalvalue.add(path2.get(index));
    }
    message.setText(config_APPLBODY+"\n"+finalvalue+"\n\n"+ config_APPLSIG);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my code : Inside the sendmail() method, am not able to get all the file names without square bracket.

For printing an `ArrayList` without the `[` and `]` characters, you can use something similar to the following:

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("Some value");
values.add("This values has [brackets] in it!");
values.add("Last value");

String commaDelim = values.toString();
commaDelim = commaDelim.substring(1, commaDelim.length()-1);
System.out.println(commaDelim);
```

**Output** `Some value, This values has [brackets] in it!, Last value`

Or you could use a for loop:

```
String commaDelim = "";
for(int i =0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    commaDelim += values.get(i);
    if(i != values.size()-1)
        commaDelim += ", ";
}

System.out.println(commaDelim);
```

**Output** `Some value, This values has [brackets] in it!, Last value`

As mentioned in the comments, I forgot about `String.join(String delim, Iteratable list)`. This method is slightly different across programming languages (i.e in PHP it is called `implode()`) and the lines below are strictly Java specific, however, the above 2 methods should work in nearly any language. This is a very simple method to achieve the same results:

```
commaDelim = String.join(", ", values);
System.out.println(commaDelim);
```

**Output** `Some value, This values has [brackets] in it!, Last value`

> Here, finalvalue is an arraylist. If i use, .get() am getting OutofBoundException.

We would need more information to determine the cause of this issue (I assume you are talking about `finalvalue.add(path2.get(index));` as that is the only `.get()` call)

A good practice when iterating arrays is to use the size of the array as the bound rather than a variable, that way you *shouldn't* ever get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception.

Comment: A more succinct way to build such a string is `String.join(",", values)`.

Comment: Oh yea, I knew I was missing something. My bad, I'll add it to my answer